# Concatenating variables in a Stylus mixin

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to make a mixin that generates some styles with variables, and I would like to concatenate two variables and I can't make it work. Here is an example:

```
centerSprite($icon)
    margin-top -(($ico_+$icon+_height) / 2)
    margin-left -(($ico_+$icon+_width) / 2)
```

I have a variable with the height and the width of an icon and I would like to to put the name in the arguments of the mixin to get that variable and make the operation...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all those variables are numbers? What css do you expect?

Comment: This would be a good candidate for a codepen or something / it's hard to tell what you are doing without the variables etc.

Comment: PS - there has got to be a better way to center those ---- show us the code! : )

Comment: @sheriffderek Normally I use the transform method to center this icons, but when I use a spritesheets like these the transform property causes weird image cuts and that is because I have to use this "centerSprite" mixin...

Comment: @MiguelMorera use SVG sprites all the time and have good luck with them. What are you using?

Comment: @sheriffderek In this project I'm using oldschool PNG sprites because... reasons. I would love to use SVG sprites too but currently it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good man [on Github](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2322#issuecomment-323328810) explained to me the [`lookup`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#lookupname) built-in function in Stylus and this is what I was looking for:

```
$ico_test_width  ?= 20px
$ico_test_height ?= 15px

centerSprite($icon)
    margin-top : -(lookup('$ico_' + $icon + '_height') / 2)
    margin-left: -(lookup('$ico_' + $icon + '_width')  / 2)

body  
    centerSprite('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (maybe a bug?) but when you have a minus before parenthesis in a property value inside a function stylus can't compile:

This code doesn't compile:

```
centerSprite()
    margin-top -((5 + 10 + 3) / 2)

body
    centerSprite()
```

But this one without function compile:

```
 body
     margin-top -((5 + 10 + 3) / 2)
```

And I have discovered if you use colons after the property works also in a function:

**Stylus**

```
centerSprite()
    margin-top: -((5 + 10 + 3) / 2)

body
    centerSprite()
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin-top: -9;
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bug. In the Github solution below, if a I don't add colons the code doesn't compile too. But the first one operator in your comment it's compiling for me.